# How do i get a div tag to only show a vertical scrollbar (and not horizontal)?

Tags: html

I have tried several incarnations of the overflow attribute in the div's style. None work for IE!

Really, I am typing into a texbox and using javascript to render the html in div of equal porportions while I type. I use  mydiv.innerHTML = txt; to populate the div. But the hortizontal scroll bar keeps appearing.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the related HTML and maybe the JS?

Answer (score 5):

try with

```
overflow-x:hidden
```